# Folder upload in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I need to upload a folder without zipping it.
Folder may also contain sub-folders and files.
Is it possible?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: do you want to use ftp?

Comment: No, i don't want to use FTP. Need to upload it from client to server.

Comment: User has to select the files. You can't from code out of the blue select a singe file, or mutliple files from code. The reason is for security. If I could write code that selects a file without user interaction, then while you visit my site to say view a cat video, I will steal all your files - I will grab your email lists, and even look for say a excel file called passwords. And I'll look for and grab and steal files called banking information. As a result, NO browser allows you or your code to select a single file, or even multiple files. Too big of a security hold and thus not allowed.

Comment: User has to select the files. You can certainly have a file upload control allow the user to say browse to a folder, open the folder and then they hit ctrl-a to select all files. But the files selected MUST occur as a result of user interaction - no browser allows any other process since it would be a huge secuirty hole. Browser code NEVER allows code to select a file, or a folder. The USER must make selections - code can't even pick the file name to up load. You can once the file been up-loaded then "save as" any name you want - client file select ONLY is by user ineratcion - not by code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User has to select the files. You can't from code out of the blue select a singe file, or multiple files from code.

The reason is for security. If I could write code that selects a file without user interaction, then while you visit my site to say view a cat video, I will steal all your files - I will grab your email lists, and even look for say a excel file called passwords. And I'll look for and grab and steal files called banking information. As a result, NO browser allows you or your code to select a single file, or even multiple files. Too big of a security hold and thus not allowed.

So your browser client side code can NOT select a file. The USER must select that file.

You can have the user browse to a folder, open it, and then say hit ctrl-A if the file upload control supports multiple file selections. But in ALL cases, the USER must select each file. You can't select a folder, nor can you with client code select a folder.

If this was possbile, then this would be a massive secuirty hole, since then any one visting any site could have the browser simply go and select any old file without the users knowledge or even controling or wanting to allow, or not allow files to be up-loaded.

So, this is a browser lockdown issue. If someone came out with a browser that allowed this, then no one would use that browser since it would be too high of a secuirty risk.

So client side code can't even set, or change select a simple single file - the USER must do this action. As a result, it not possible to select even a folder to up-load - the user must do this.

So you can adopt one of many file up-load controls that allows the user to make multiple selections - but that multiple selection of a single file, or many files MUST occur by user actions selecting files - client side code can NEVER select, pick or choose a file name for security reason. Only USER actions can select a file - never client side code - it simply not allowed, and it simply never going to be allowed for reasons of security.

So a file control that allows multiple file selections - to allow the user to select all the files in a folder quickly? yes, but no folder selecting is allowed. The user will have to browse to the folder - select files to upload. They could then open/add another folder and select files from that folder. But no folder, or even a simple single file can be obtained, picked or touched or used by client side code.

Comment: Thank you @Albert for your expert advice. I was not sure if uploading all the files in folder and its sub-folders were possible without selecting them first so I raised this question. Your answer have given me clarity.

Comment: User is of course free to zip up a folder and up-load that. But the end user has to do this - browsers are locked down in code that can EVEN select a file name - it not a possibility for security reasons. I suppose you could offer users a small desktop program - say written in .net that lets them select folders - and that desktop program would do the upload. But browsers are what we call a "sand box", and file operations are VERY limited. If access to files and folders was not VERY limited, then browsers would be  security nightmare - no one would use them if they could steal/select files.

Answer (score 1):

could be one of these links:
First: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/upload-file-to-web-site

Second: https://qawithexperts.com/article/asp-net/file-upload-in-aspnet-web-forms-upload-control-example/273